# How to save data immediately to the database using Spring Boot and JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to save some data into the database using **save** from JPA Repository.
I have the call to save method in another method. The problem is that the entity created is not saved after .save() is called. I have to access the index from the saved data but because the mentioned data is not saved I get "Index -1 out of bounds for length 0". After this, I think it rolles back because the execution continues.
The code is the following:

```
    public void method(Double number, Integer entityId){
        Entity entity= findById(entityId);

        CalculatedValue calculatedValue= new CalculatedValue ();
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        monitoredValue.setDateTime(dateTime);

        List<CalculatedValue > calculatedValueList= calculatedValueservice.findAllById(entityId);

        if(calculatedValueList.isEmpty()){
            calculatedValue.setValue(0.0);
            calculatedValue.setEntity(entity);
            calculatedValueRespository.save(calculatedValue);
            
        }


        CaclulatedValue lastCalculatedValue = calculatedValueList.get(calculatedValueList.size() - 1);
}
```

My question is: how do I save the **calculatedValue** to the database in such way that I can have elements in the **lastCalculatedValue** list and access their indexes?

Comment: There are two possibilities that come to my mind: either cross a `@Transactional` boundary (this will commit the transaction and thus generate the primary key) or if you are using a [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) call `saveAndFlush(...)` instead of `save(...)`.

Comment: I have tried both, saveAndFlush() unfortunately does not save the data either ( I think it is related to the fact that I call it from another method). @Transactional also stops my method from rolling-back and executing the rest of the code. With this annotation, nothing is saved to the db.. only the exception appears.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood the question. Is your porblem that the newly persisted entity is not part of the `calculatedValueList`?

Comment: @Turing85 yes, exactly

Comment: Why not simply add it to the list after persisting? `calculatedValueList = List.of(calculatedValueRespository.save(calculatedValue));` (this is rectified since `calculatedValueList` is empty)

Comment: Also, you might want to rethink some of your naming. Names like method and entity don't really help to understand your code. It would be easier to understand and think about/work with your code if you put some extra effort in good names.

Comment: Oh that solved my problem. I though that somehow it will add more elements to the list. But it makes sense now, cause I do this only in the situation when the list is empty. Thank you very much! @Turing85

Comment: @Myii The `List` is fetched at some point in time. The list represents the state of the database at that point in time. If we modify the database afterwards, the changes are not reflected in the `List`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list will not be updated automatically. You have to add the new element manually

```
List<CalculatedValue > calculatedValueList= calculatedValueservice.findAllById(entityId);

        if(calculatedValueList.isEmpty()){
            calculatedValue.setValue(0.0);
            calculatedValue.setEntity(entity);
            calculatedValueRespository.save(calculatedValue);
            // ADD IT MANUALLY
            calculatedValueList.add(calculatedValue)
        }
```